# How to play piano with both hands?

Tags: piano, performing

I took piano lessons since fifth grade and stopped in eighth grade. I have been taught to play with hands seperate instead of playing with both hands. I have attempted this but I keep messing up.It's been almost four years ever since I played the piano. I am trying to teach myself to play the piano since I don't have time to go to piano lessons and they are expensive. Has anyone had trouble playing with both hands and how did you end up mastering this skill? So I can try it for myself and hopefully get the same results. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't identical, but I think your answer is here: [Learn piano one hand at a time or simultaneously?](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/39871/learn-piano-one-hand-at-a-time-or-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a piano noob and I face this problem every time I try to learn a new piece.

Many people go for the "Three Time" thing (once with the right hand, once with the left hand, and then playing with them together). I have found that it doesn't really work for me.

So I try to play the piece *really* slowly with both hands at once so I know which fingers play together and which ones to alternate.

Plus you could try playing scales with both hands at a time (which I guess you already did when you took classes).

You'll have to try the "Three Time" method or the "Both hands together *slowly*" method or any method you can think of and see which one really works for *you*.

Let me know if the answer needs any clarification.